# Strange problem: black screen when selecting live ubuntu or install ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

I've putted ubuntu to a flash drive and came to grub menu selected try ubuntu live the screen goes black with some words"acpi pcc probe failed" then the screen goes totally black,
 I've tested the monitor on another PC and it worked fine,
i restarted the PC and came to grub menu again and selected install ubuntu first was the same as selected live ubuntu but the second the setup started fine!!!
 i installed the system and after i finished restarted the PC and again like the first time the screen goes black after i selected the system to boot ):
 i tried to select advanced options for ubuntu then start ubuntu in recovery mode there i selected resume normal boot and it worked and booted to ubuntu fine!!?
but i still wondering the reason to this problem??
my graphic card is radeon hd 5450 and the hard is gpt
i tried before installing opensuse but it's the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
i tried pressing F6 on Grub boot menu and selected nomodeset in it work but
after installing Ubuntu and reboot the screen resolution are low 640x480 and the monitor is unknown!!
now trying something else